# No Gender Nouns

Tags: american-english, british-english, history, old-english

Why do adjectives and some nouns in English not have gender?
Is there a history beyond that? 
Don't this cause some ambiguity in the language itself?

Comment: Could make for a good question. Please expand your question. Also include your background effort done. Good Luck.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See also [ell.se].

Comment: What do you mean, "some nouns"? In English, absolutely no nouns at all have gender.

Comment: Some words do such as: man, woman, girl and so on.